# Python 3rd Party Modules in AWS Lambda through Cloud9

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I had a quick question. I recently started to learn python and have been using Cloud9 as my environment. I've created a code for Alexa in python that uses BeautifulSoup, meaning that AWS Lambda throws an error every time I run it (as it does not recognize BeautifulSoup as a model). I was wondering, since I'm working in Cloud9, how do I allow/permit AWS Lambda to work with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 2):

To actually install the BS library, you'll need to use [Pip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-python.html#sample-python-sdk). That will get it working in Cloud9. When you use the function in Lambda, it will require a [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) that also includes the BS library.

The error you are getting probably relates to the library not existing in the Lambda environment.

If Cloud9 doesn't make it easy to export a deployment package, you might have to [upload code manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I do get the 3rd party modules to work in Cloud 9, the issue comes when I want to run the code in AWS Lambda. I don't think Cloud9 or AWS have added any feature export a deployment package, but I'm sure they will in the future (It would make Alexa Skills development so much easier!)